# ZF2 Coding Standards

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm looking to find a page of coding standards for Zend Framework 2. The reference used to have a page for it in version 1.x of the framework, but I cannot seem to find it anymore.

Specifically, I'm trying to deliver table + field name documentation to another developer I will be working with who's primary responsibility will be database engineering and maintenance. He has never worked with the ZF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ZF2 follows mainly [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) coding standard (implies also PSR-1)

For rules not defined by PSR-2 then exists this article in the official page http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/coding.standard.html